# Youtube Audio and Video go out of sync in Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, audio, youtube

I have a client on Windows 10 using the latest version of Chrome.

When they start a youtube video, it is in sync. However, after getting a few minutes into it, it goes significantly out of sync (about a 1sec delay).

This issue is also coupled with another more minor issue of if they scroll a page while viewing a youtube video, you hear a popping noise.

I can't figure out what would be causing this. The audio card is built into the motherboard. All drivers are up to date, Windows is up to date, and chrome is up to date.

The client does have some Chrome extensions installed and enabled: Checker Plus for Gmail, Grammarly, Honey, LastPass, MixMax, Momentum, Pay by Privacy.com, Todoist, and uBlock Origin.

This problem also occurs in Edge. No testing has been done in Firefox.

Comment: Not able to replicate.

Comment: OK, please click [edit] and post your new can't-replicate-elsewhere findings in your original question. Comments are for us to ask you stuff; all your responses should go into the Question so all can see everything you've discovered in one place. Also, if you install Firefox or Chromium https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/en/ & run it w no extensions, do you see the undesired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a confirmation, do other video broadcast websites have the same problem?

If it only happens to YouTube, you could refer to the following steps:

1. Delete all your cookies and cached images from chrome for all time.
2. Sign out of your Google account and open YouTube.
3. Open YouTube and click settings in the top right and sign into your account from there. (it will look really weird to do, not like the usual login for your account).
4. Once this is done close the tab you used to login to YouTube.
5. Open a new tab and open YouTube again (either through favourites or typing it in).
6. Sign into your account via the button in the top right corner and the issue should be fixed.

Source: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-3423664/youtube-videos-audio-sync.html#r20533942

If it is common, reinstall the graphics drivers and try with a shorter HDMI cable.

Hope these are helpful.

Comment: It happened to be the graphics driver. Very weird because my audio is completely separate from the graphics (No HDMI etc.), but an out of date AMD Radeon driver was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, found Chrome add-on [h264ify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/h264ify/aleakchihdccplidncghkekgioiakgal), and now the syncing is perfect (works best if Hardware Acceleration is disabled in Chrome's settings).

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your sound/video is out of sync.
Go to: Control panel - Sound.   Choose active speakers and right click - click properties - click the advanced tab - then uncheck "activate enhanced sound".